# Problem after update expo sdk 44 -> 47: Java.lang.double cannot be cast to abi47*___0_0.com.facebook.react.vbridge.ReadableMap*

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I needed to update the expo sdk version (due to the minimum version of ios to bundle with apple)

And when updating from version 44 to 47, I got the following error when run the app (expo start): Java.lang.double cannot be cast to abi47*___0_0.com.facebook.react.vbridge.ReadableMap*

I performed the update gradually, going from 44 to 45, from 45 to 46 and then to 47,
Fixed some libraries that were breaking.

- I was using react-native-appearance and switched to react core
- I made a direct change in the lib due to viewproptypes (deprecated-react-native-prop-types)
- Removed expo-app-loading because it is deprecated

*Obs*: I try to use another version of react-native-svg - 12.1.0, but it just made expo drop an alert about expected version vs installed version

Expo doctor not return anything.

---

[tag:Node version: 16.18.0]

My package.json

```
{
"name": "teste",
"version": "1.0.0",
"scripts": {
"start": "expo start --dev-client",
"android": "expo run:android",
"ios": "expo run:ios",
"web": "expo start --web",
"eject": "expo eject",
"create-component": "plop"
},
"dependencies": {
"@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication": "^2.2.2",
"@miblanchard/react-native-slider": "^2.1.0",
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "\~1.17.3",
"@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "6.5.2",
"@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^8.2.1",
"@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "0.2.8",
"@react-native-picker/picker": "2.4.8",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.14",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.5",
"@types/uuid": "^8.3.4",
"axios": "^1.2.0",
"deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^2.3.0",
"expo": "^47.0.0",
"expo-app-loading": "\~2.1.1",
"expo-apple-authentication": "\~5.0.1",
"expo-asset": "\~8.6.2",
"expo-auth-session": "\~3.7.2",
"expo-camera": "\~13.1.0",
"expo-clipboard": "\~4.0.1",
"expo-constants": "\~14.0.2",
"expo-dev-client": "\~2.0.1",
"expo-font": "\~11.0.1",
"expo-image-manipulator": "\~11.0.0",
"expo-image-picker": "\~14.0.2",
"expo-linking": "\~3.2.3",
"expo-location": "\~15.0.1",
"expo-random": "\~13.0.0",
"expo-secure-store": "\~12.0.0",
"expo-splash-screen": "\~0.17.5",
"expo-status-bar": "\~1.4.2",
"expo-system-ui": "\~2.0.1",
"expo-updates": "\~0.15.6",
"i18n-js": "^4.2.0",
"i18next": "^22.0.6",
"lottie-react-native": "5.1.4",
"moment": "^2.29.4",
"pluralize": "^8.0.0",
"react": "18.1.0",
"react-dom": "18.1.0",
"react-i18next": "^12.0.0",
"react-native": "0.70.5",
"react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
"react-native-appearance": "^0.3.4",
"react-native-confetti-cannon": "^1.5.2",
"react-native-fbsdk-next": "^11.1.0",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "\~2.8.0",
"react-native-get-random-values": "\~1.8.0",
"react-native-image-pan-zoom": "^2.1.12",
"react-native-iphone-x-helper": "^1.3.1",
"react-native-linear-gradient": "2.6.2",
"react-native-masked-text": "^1.13.0",
"react-native-mime-types": "^2.3.0",
"react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "4.4.1",
"react-native-screens": "\~3.18.0",
"react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
"react-native-svg": "^12.1.0",
"react-native-toast-message": "^2.1.5",
"react-native-web": "\~0.18.7",
"react-redux": "^8.0.5",
"redux": "^4.2.0",
"redux-thunk": "^2.4.2",
"styled-components": "^5.3.6",
"styled-system": "^5.1.5",
"uuid": "^9.0.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.19.3",
"@types/react": "\~18.0.24",
"@types/react-native": "\~0.70.6",
"@types/react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.8.5",
"@types/styled-components-react-native": "^5.2.0",
"@types/styled-system": "^5.1.15",
"plop": "^3.1.1",
"typescript": "^4.6.3"
},
"private": true
}
```